# What caused everyone forgetting the Beatles and other things?

Tags: yesterday-2019

In the film *Yesterday*, there’s a blackout for 12 seconds in which everyone, other than Jack<sup>1</sup>, forgets about the Beatles, and any evidence of the band existing is removed from the face of the earth. The band Oasis doesn't exist (the implication being that they derived everything from the Beatles) but

> John Lennon still existed and, as he wasn't ever famous, was never murdered.

Also,

> cigarettes, Coca-Cola, and *Harry Potter* don't exist.

Obviously, the out-of-universe explanation for how this happened is that it was to make a funny movie. **But have the writers/director said what caused it in-universe?**

<sup>1</sup>

> and two other people

Comment: /spoiler Jack is not the only one to remember the things you mentioned. Also not only has the evidence of the bands that existed been erased, it seems that the entire reality was warped and that they have truly never existed in the new timeline. (John Lennon being alive an all)

Comment: @TerranGaming yes it just seemed like a kind of irrelevant spoiler to put in the question.

Comment: He's in a comma after the accident & the whole thing is fantasy wish fulfilment going on in his mind? the only hard science / reality answer that fits the facts available to us (that I've found) with no loose ends .. but that's not a very satisfying answer so hopefully it's not the right one.

Comment: The band is called ___The___ Beatles. Why’d you rollback the edit?

Answer (score 3):

Danny Boyle, the director, states a few times in an interview with Entertainment Weekly that it is an alternate world. Therefore, it's not that everyone forgets The Beatles, it's that they never existed in the first place.

> Director Danny Boyle tells EW he had a similar reaction when he first read the scene in Richard Curtis’ script. “When I read it, emotionally, I was overwhelmed by it,” he says. “When you work on a movie, you’re very conscious of time. And I don’t mean a producer shouting, ‘You’re running out of time.’ You can crush time or expand it. You stop it, you start it. You can do wondrous things in time in cinema. **This premise is an alternate timeline, and it can show you something wondrous where violence can be defeated. Something horrible we imagine for a moment never to have happened.**”
>
> [...]
>
> While it may not be everyone’s favorite part of the film, Boyle says it’s the scene he’s most proud of. “It’s a very affectionate and beautiful portrait of someone that we love. Wouldn’t things be wonderful if we hadn’t lost him?” he muses. “**In this alternate world, he’s still there and he lived a very happy life without the fame, without the glory, without the pressure.** He’s still done the most fundamental thing, which is find the girl that he loved and told her so, and actually got on with his life with her and lived a happy life with her. It’s very basic, but I was very, very moved by that within what is a very light romantic comedy. There’s a very profound idea within it.”
>
> <sub>[Entertainment Weekly, Danny Boyle explains how they pulled off that gasp-inducing Beatles moment in *Yesterday*](https://ew.com/movies/2019/06/29/danny-boyle-beatles-twist-yesterday/)</sub>

---

<sub>***Disclaimer:** I haven't seen the film but from the interview and reading around (and my own impression initially) it does seem like setting it in an alternate world makes sense.*</sub>

Comment: So he just leaves it at “it’s an alternate timeline”. I guess that’s as good an answer as I’ll get.

Comment: Does this mean the Beatles never exist in the film at all? The whole thing is an alternate timeline and Jack only imagines the band he gets his inspiration from?

Comment: @Jontia : No, Yes, No, in that order.

Comment: An alternate timeline is a destination, not a journey. It's the What that forms this question not the How that would be an answer.

Comment: @Pelinore if the question was "What caused everyone to become evil and Klingons to be in charge in the DS9 episode [Crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine))" would it's an alternative universe be the right answer, or would you point to there being something wrong with the shuttle during the wormhole transit? It's an Alternative Universe is trivially true not relevant to how it happens.

Comment: @Jontia My answer here is that The Beatles never existed in that timeline and therefore _that_ is the question to why everyone forgot. It's not that they forgot, it's that they had nothing to forget in the first place because they were never around.

Comment: @Jontia : No, that doesn't mean the Beatles never exist in the film at all : Yes, The whole thing is an alternate timeline : No, Jack doesn't only imagines the band he gets his inspiration from.

Answer (score -3):

So, this information is based only on watching the Trailer, but it seemed kind of obvious and I can't add a clip to a comment.

Jack's dead. He's been t-boned by a car whilst on a bicycle during a world-wide power blackout. Everything that happens at this point is in heaven/hell/purgatory/mid-life reincarnation. It's your choice, but in our universe Jack didn't walk away from this accident.

Comment: It'd be a reasonable explanation except for the two other people knowing.

Comment: As a film maker (or TVTropes It Just Bugs Me reader), I'd put something in there to suggest they died at the same time. But I don't know if they did this in the film. It's still on my +List.

Comment: Nothing a quick Google popped up produces anything to dispute the idea but without any more detail than is available from the trailer, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesterday_(2019_film)) or elsewhere I can find there are any number of other explanations that would be equally valid : he's in a comma & it's all in his mind, 'god' (aliens or some other entity) reset reality in some way somehow & his memory somehow fell through the cracks, he somehow shifted to an alternate reality (or his mind switched with or replaced that of the 'him' in an alternate reality) .. 1/2

Comment: I could probably go on, but the point is there's nothing available that I can find that definitively gives your answer any more validity than a number of other potential answers? .. 2/2

Comment: @Pelinore only the logic of film making. Things happen on screen for a reason. Why have a potentially fatal bike accident at the time the universe changes if it is not the reason for the change. There could be something else going On, but as it even say in the question everyone forgets the Beatles because it is a film where everyone forgets the Beatles. Death is a good reason for an adventure backed by the clip and so that's my answer.

Comment: The 'logic of film making' applies equally well to a number of other potential answers that can also be 'backed by that clip', that was my point, surprised you seem to have failed to get that, sans a statement direct from the film makers or writer (the only one of which I'm aware of, from the other answer, supports an alternate world answer rather than yours) what makes yours more plausible than any of the others?

Comment: @Pelinore I'd be very interested to know what other trigger events you have seen in the clip.

Comment: My feeling is that even though there is always a reason for what is on film, that reason can be any number of things. Establishing someone's character, preserving verisimilitude, saving money for the production or even saving effort for the actors. Even an in-joke or Easter Egg (Mace Windu didn't have a purple lightsaber because he balanced the two sides of the Force with Vaapad, he had it because purple was his actor's favorite color). Plot is just one of many reasons for what we see on screen.

Comment: Who needs other trigger events, I'll rephrase, _"The 'logic of film making' applies equally well to a number of other potential answers that can also be backed by that **trigger event**"_, what makes yours more plausible.

Comment: @Pelinore, what others? Give me an example to work with.

Comment: @Pelinore I have comprehension issue with what you're trying to ask me. Let me see if I have this right, you would like me to explain why Jack dies in accident and is given an amazing new life for unspecified reasons is more plausible than any other possible explanation for The Beatles being erased from existence? But despite there being many other 'potential answers' in the trailer you don't want to throw out an alternative for me to shoot down?

Comment: I haven't asked you anything (even if there has been the odd rhetorical question scattered in there), I've told you something, that your answer is no more plausible with the clip (OR 'trigger events') than others that all fit that 'trigger event' equally well & are just as plausible : no further 'trigger events' other than the one you use are needed to support them : I gave you three alternatives already, I suggest you read what you're replying to because they're already there.

Comment: Right, missed the aliens did it bit.  Ok so God or aliens did it is the same as saying he died and turned up somewhere else. Him being in a coma and dreaming is fundamentally the same, because he is in a Bike accident he doesn't walk away from. He falls through a hole or being brain switched to an alternate reality has no foundation in the clip because there's a Bike accident, not a ball of wibbly wobbly time whimey stuff.